# Retrieve Authorization Status for Core Location

Tags: ios, core-location

Apple has deprecated the `authorizationStatus` method. Is there a way to know which is the status of the authorisation for my App?
Let's say that a user granted the permission in a previous session and with another app session I wanted to show or hide a button depending on the fact that the user has granted the permission or not. How can I get this information now that `authorizationStatus` is no longer available?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/3563956-locationmanagerdidchangeauthoriz) delegate.

Answer (score 0):

see documentation: [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager):

> class func authorizationStatus() -> CLAuthorizationStatus
> is deprecated.

there are new instance property that available since iOS 14

> var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus - The current
> authorization status for the app.